# Problem with Touchpad on Fedora23

Tags: fedora, touchpad

I have installed *Fedora 23* on my *Dell Vostro* 3550 Laptop.
But my touchpad is not working properly. When I am holding a finger on my TouchPad, the pointer on the Screen is flicking all the time. That never happens on Windows though. I think there is some problem with touchpad driver in fedora.

Can anyone suggest what driver I should install to make TouchPad work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself. I have just installed available synaptics drivers. Then created a link namely `99-syanptics.conf` targeted to `50-synaptics.conf` , as after some research I came to know that `99-syanptics.conf` should be the actual configuration file for my machine.

```
    dnf install xorg-x11-drv-synaptics*
    cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
    ln -s 50-synaptics.conf 99-synaptics.conf
```

N.B. - A reboot needed after this.

Thank you GAD3R for helping me with hints. :D

Answer (score 2):

**GNOME**

The "mouse and touchpad" utility can be used to enable tapping and set scrolling options in GNOME.

**KDE Plasma Workspaces**

enter KDE System Settings

choose Hardware / Input Devices / Touchpad (If it's not there, install kcm_touchpad first, then restart System Settings. It's installed by default.)

select the Tapping tab

check the "Enable tapping" checkbox

set some tapping actions under "Buttons" below, the default is to do nothing
Alternatively, the systemwide method described under Other window managers can also be used.

**LXDE**

Copy the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf file to

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

```
cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Then, in your favourite text editor, modify this file as such:

```
      Section  "InputClass"
      Identifier  "touchpad catchall"
      Driver  "synaptics"
      MatchIsTouchpad  "on"

     ####################################
     ## The lines that you need to add ##
     # Enable left mouse button by tapping
     Option  "TapButton1"  "1"
    # Enable vertical scrolling
    Option  "VertEdgeScroll"  "1"
    # Enable right mouse button by tapping lower right corner
    Option "RBCornerButton" "3"
     ####################################

    MatchDevicePath  "/dev/input/event*"
    EndSection
```

**XFCE**

Copy the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf file to

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

```
cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Then, in your favourite text editor, modify the new file as such:

```
      Section  "InputClass"
      Identifier  "touchpad catchall"
      Driver  "synaptics"
      MatchIsTouchpad  "on"

      ####################################
      ## The lines that you need to add ##
      # Enable left mouse button by tapping
      Option  "TapButton1"  "1"
      # Enable vertical scrolling
      Option  "VertEdgeScroll"  "1"
     # Enable right mouse button by tapping lower right corner
      Option "RBCornerButton" "3"
      ####################################

     MatchDevicePath  "/dev/input/event*"
     EndSection
```

**MATE**

Copy the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

```
cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Then, in your favourite text editor, modify this file as such:

```
      Section  "InputClass"
      Identifier  "touchpad catchall"
      Driver  "synaptics"
      MatchIsTouchpad  "on"

      ####################################
      ## The lines that you need to add ##
      # Enable left mouse button by tapping
      Option  "TapButton1"  "1"
      # Enable vertical scrolling
      Option  "VertEdgeScroll"  "1"
      # Enable right mouse button by tapping lower right corner
      Option "RBCornerButton" "3"
      ####################################

      MatchDevicePath  "/dev/input/event*"
      EndSection
```

I get the answer from fedoraproject.org

Comment: That was a quite broad and clear answer. Thanks for your quick response. I got hints from your answer and solved myself.